# How can I use an utf-8 file name retrieved from a YAML file for os.path.isdir()?

Tags: python, utf-8, yaml, ruamel.yaml

I am loading a folder path from a config.yml file. Example name: `C:/Users/Name/Desktop/ü` which contains an utf-8 character. When I load this path using `yaml.load(config)` (I am using ruamel.yaml) and then use the loaded value to check if this directory exists with `os.path.isdir()` I always get back "False", even though the file exists. (on Windows)

However, when I try to check if the file exists with a hardcoded string like `root_path = 'C:/Users/Name/Desktop/ü'` I get "True".

I dumped the data (a python dict) to the config file using yaml.dump():

```py
with open(path_to_config, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as config:
    yaml.dump(data, config)
```

which looks like this when opening in a text editor:

```
destination:
  root_path: C:/Users/Name/Desktop/ü
```

Printing the hardcoded value to the console shows:

```
C:/Users/Name/Desktop/▒
```

or when using `print(root_path.encode('utf-8'))`:

`b'C:/Users/Name/Desktop/\xc3\xbc`.

To retrieve the root_path from the config file I use:

```py
with open('config.yaml') as cfg:
    user_data = yaml.load(cfg)
    root_path = user_data['destination']['root_path']
```

When I print the root_path retrieved from the config.yml file instead I get:

```
C:/Users/Name/Desktop/ü
```

and using `print(root_path.encode('utf-8'))`:

```
b'C:/Users/Name/Desktop/\xc3\x83\xc2\xbc'
```

Where does this difference come from and how can I convert the value loaded from the config file so that os.path.isdir() can find the file?

Comment: Please expand your post (while keeping it a single coherent whole, so no **EDIT:**), where you provide a complete, minimal, program. How exactly did you make the file, did you dump from YAML? My guess is that either the file is opened `"r"`, where it probably should be opened `"rb"`, or that the encoding of the YAML file is UTF-16 without a recognised/recognisable BOM.

Comment: Wow, your suggestion worked. Thank you so much! How should I make others aware that your comment worked? Edit my post and reference your anwer?

Comment: I'll write an answer, but it is still useful to make your question a bit more complete.

Comment: Done. Is the edit ok?

Comment: That looks much more complete, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most examples you'll see reading a YAML file from disc is done using:

```
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
with open('config.yaml') as fp:
    yaml.load(fp)
```

That open, is an open for reading (same as doing `open("config.yaml", "r")`). That is fine on Linux, or on Windows when using ASCII/text files. But in order for the YAML parser to properly handle non-ASCII input on Windows, you should open the file in read-binary mode:

```
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
with open('config.yaml', 'rb') as fp:
    yaml.load(fp)
```